# Find a property inside a class that match List<class>

Tags: vb.net, reflection, types

For the display of a list of item, I need to know with generic way to determine if item has a list of this item, it is a simple recursive loop.

I have tried with Reflection as this

```
Dim detail As New List(Of PersonneSampleModel) From {New PersonneSampleModel With {.Id = 50, .Nom = "Details_Robert", .Prenom = "Details_titi"}}

Dim p = New PersonneSampleModel With {.Id = 1, .Nom = "Robert", .Prenom = "titi", .lst = detail}
Dim p2 = New PersonneSampleModel With {.Id = 2, .Nom = "Jean", .Prenom = "titi2"}
Dim p3 = New PersonneSampleModel With {.Id = 3, .Nom = "Dupont", .Prenom = "titi3"}
Dim p4 = New PersonneSampleModel With {.Id = 4, .Nom = "Sean", .Prenom = "titi3"}
Dim p5 = New PersonneSampleModel With {.Id = 5, .Nom = "Paul", .Prenom = "titi3"}
Dim p6 = New PersonneSampleModel With {.Id = 6, .Nom = "Durant", .Prenom = "titi3"}
Dim lst As New List(Of PersonneSampleModel) From {p, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6}

For Each item In lst
    For Each prop in item.GetType().GetProperties           
        If TypeOf prop Is List(of PersonneSampleModel) ' <= how to determine if prop is List<item> 
            prop.Dump()
        End if          
    Next
Next
```

Not Working :

```
If TypeOf prop Is List(of item.GetType()) 'item.GetType() not defined

If TypeOf prop Is List(of PersonneSampleModel) ' PropertyInfo is not List(of )
```

My issue is that prop is ever PropertyInfo and not a true type that I can compare.

Thank for your help.

EDIT:

Some test passed and I have found this, the last thing is how to replace prop.Name = "lst" by prop.Type = typeof(item)

```
For Each item In lst
    item.Dump("item")
    item.lst.Dump("item.lst")
    For Each prop in item.GetType().GetProperties           
        if prop.Name = "lst"
            dim l As new List(Of PersonneSampleModel) 
            l = item.GetType().GetProperty("lst").GetValue(item, nothing)       
            l.Dump("Value")
            prop.Dump("prop")
        end if 
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Why cant you use `If item.lst IsNot Nothing Then...` instead of reflection?

Comment: Because I don't know the name of the property. I know only that class has a property that is List<class> to made a recursive loop.

Comment: The code is looking for `PersonneSampleModel` type, so how would it not know the props for that Type?

Comment: It represent an implementation. It would be PersonneSampleModel or FooSampleModel or anything class with a property List<class>. And I do retrieve this property.

Comment: Correct me if I'm mistaken, but as your code stands, it is checking each item in the list to see if the item is a list of  PersonneSampleModel, But the items in the list you created are not lists of PersonneSampleModel, they are just PersonneSampleModel objects.

Comment: I have edited my original post. In each PersonneSampleModel, I have List<PersonneSampleModel, so I do iterate a list and found the property in each object if I found another List<T>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `MakeGenericType()` method to create the typed list type at runtime and then compare it with the property type.

```
For Each item In lst
    For Each prop in item.GetType().GetProperties       
        If GetType(List(of )).MakeGenericType(item.GetType()) = prop.PropertyType Then
            Dim innerList = prop.GetValue(item)
            If innerList IsNot Nothing Then
                Console.WriteLine("list found")
            End if
        End if          
    Next
Next
```